# Error Generating Classes for JOOQ WIndows

Tags: mysql, jooq

Trying to [generate the necessary classes for a jooq program](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.4/manual/getting-started/tutorials/jooq-in-7-steps/jooq-in-7-steps-step3/).

I have all three jars, the java connector, and a prop file in a temp location. But when I run:

```
java -classpath jooq-1.6.8.jar:jooq-meta-1.6.8.jar:jooq-codegen-1.6.8.jar:mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar:. org.jooq.util.GenerationTool /jooq.properties
```

It says: Error : Could not find or load main class org.jooq.util.GenerationTool

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [manual](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/tutorials/jooq-in-7-steps/jooq-in-7-steps-step3/) that you've linked says:

> Once you have the JAR files and library.xml in your temp directory, type this on a Windows machine:
>
> ```
> java -classpath jooq-3.4.1.jar;jooq-meta-3.4.1.jar;jooq-codegen-3.4.1.jar;mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar;. org.jooq.util.GenerationTool /library.xml
> ```
>
> ... or type this on a UNIX / Linux / Mac system (colons instead of semi-colons):
>
> ```
> java -classpath jooq-3.4.1.jar:jooq-meta-3.4.1.jar:jooq-codegen-3.4.1.jar:mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar:. org.jooq.util.GenerationTool /library.xml
> ```

You chose unix separators (colon `:`) to separate classpath elements, instead of Windows separators (semicolon `;`).

Also, consider upgrading to the latest version

Comment: Its still not working for me, I am getting the same error.

Comment: @RabiaNazkhan: The error always has the same reason: An incorrectly set up class path. Why it's incorrect for you is best seen if you ask a new question with your exact details. I'll answer there...

Comment: Thanks @Lukas Eder for your reply. I got the solution of my problem, I was using jars for 3.8.2 but I had jdk of 1.6. when I used jars 3.6.4 with jdk 1.6 it worked fine!

Comment: @RabiaNazkhan: I see, yes from jOOQ 3.7 onwards, the jOOQ Open Source Edition no longer supports JDK 1.6. If you want to upgrade to the latest jOOQ version, the commercial distributions still support Java 6...

Comment: But why it didn't supported JDK 1.7? I had it too in my environment variable.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same problem. `org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool` should be used  instead of `org.jooq.util.GenerationTool`:

```
java -classpath jooq-3.11.0.jar:jooq-meta-3.11.0.jar:jooq-codegen-3.11.0.jar:mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:. org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool library.xml
```